# Best way to parse Android / Java SoapObject return data

Tags: java, android

I have some data return from SoapObject (Android / Java)

```
final SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
SoapObject so = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
```

this is how data looks like:

> anyType{DocumentElement=anyType{Tabela=anyType{WER=1; TYU=0; NNN=0;
>   ABC=0; BBB=Napoje; }; Tabela=anyType{WER=201; TYU=0; NNN=0; ABC=0;
>   BBB=Alkohole; }; Tabela=anyType{WER=501; TYU=0; NNN=0; ABC=0;
>   BBB=Pizza; }; Tabela=anyType{WER=601; TYU=0; NNN=0; ABC=0; BBB=Desery;
>   };

I should parse that (like a String with Regex) or I can do it in better way?

Comment: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data

Answer (score 1):

I had created a demo application for parsing the SOAP Response. Also if you want to convert the SOAP response in XML response and parse that can also be done. Checkout my [example from my github source](https://github.com/lalit3686/SOAPExample/blob/master/src/com/soap/SoapHelper.java)

Comment: I'have created something like Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(WER=)(\\d*); (TYU=)(\\d*); (BBB=)(\\w*); (NNN=)(\\d*);"); and it helps me get strings from received data.